# Why TSQL convert a function's result in one way and a character string to other way?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, binary, md5

I try this command in SQL Server 2005 to obtain a MD5 from '123':

```
select SUBSTRING(sys.fn_sqlvarbasetostr(HASHBYTES('MD5',  '123' )), 3, 32)
```

and I get this result:

```
202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
```

I want to convert to binary format,

```
select 
   convert(varbinary(16), SUBSTRING(sys.fn_sqlvarbasetostr(HASHBYTES('MD5',  '123')), 3, 32))
```

And I get this result:

```
0x32003000320063006200390036003200
```

Why does this code:

```
select convert(varbinary(16), '202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70')
```

result in a different value?

```
0x32303263623936326163353930373562
```

Comment: Try this:  `select convert(varbinary(16), N'202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70')`... notice the `N` before the string to make the subsequent string Unicode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## "Regular Character Type" vs Unicode

This performs a conversion from **Nvarchar**(Unicode) to **Varbinary**

```
select convert(varbinary(16),SUBSTRING(sys.fn_sqlvarbasetostr(HASHBYTES('MD5',  '123' )),3,32))
```

By default, putting text in single quotes uses regular character types like Char or Varchar. This performs a conversion from **Varchar**("Regular Data Type") to **Varbinary**

```
select convert(varbinary(16),'202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70')
```

**Try this:**

```
SELECT CONVERT(varbinary(16), N'202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70')
```

The "N" before the quote defines the value as Nvarchar(Unicode) and you get your desired value

```
0x32003000320063006200390036003200
```

Hope this helps!